# Should I use PhoneGap even if I do not need to use any of its features such as the app stores or native device APIs

Tags: html, cordova

I am building an application with the following requirements:

- Must run on both mobile phones and tablets
- Must support online/offline scenarios
- Requires geolocation
- Requires local storage
- Platform is unknown at the moment (due to the nature of this project, I cannot yet rely on a particular platform version, e.g. Android 4+ or Windows 8.1)

I am leaning towards building this in HTML5/CSS/jQuery/Bootstrap. Since HTML5 supports both geolocation and local storage, and since I do not need to use any device feature such as a camera, I don't think something like PhoneGap is necessary.

However, as I am new to mobile development and PhoneGap, I am not sure if I am missing something. Are there any reasons - apart from future-proofing against future requirements - why I should consider using PhoneGap even though I don't think I need it for any particular reason? Is there value in having its API sitting in front of any interaction with the devices upon which my application will be running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factors to consider with respect to Local Storage.
**Local Storage size limit:**
Web storage provides far greater storage capacity (5 MB per origin in Google Chrome,Mozilla Firefox,and Opera; 10 MB per storage area in Internet Explorer;25MB per origin on BlackBerry 10 devices) compared to 4 kB (around 1000 times less space) available to cookies. ( source [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage))
**Local Storage Method.**
Web Storage:
Web SQL Database:
Indexed Database:
File Access:
source: [html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage), [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-browser-storage-past-present-future/)

All **MOBILE** broswers have varying degree of support for above local storage method.
The most widely supported method is **Web Storage**.
If you would like to store **more than the limits** mentioned above than you need to use the native (OS) features for storing data. Then **PhoneGap** is the obvious choice for accessing native features.

Answer (score 0):

How are you planning to distribute your app!! If you want to distribute using a website, then may be you don't need phonegap. BUT..... if you want it as an **mobile app**, then you'll need phonegap to easily wrap your code. Phonegap will help you to build installation package for many platforms (e.g. APK for android)